# Angular | monitor the variable

Tags: javascript, angular

Need to monitor the variable.
When executed the following line in main-list.component.ts:

```
this.environmentService.leftSideBarMainListIsOpen = false;
```

It is necessary that the class is automatically changed. Without reuse the following code:

```
this.class = this.environmentService.leftSideBarMainListIsOpen 
?'display' : 'hide';
```

And after execute the next line in main-list.component.ts:

```
this.environmentService.leftSideBarFormListIsOpen = true;
```

It is necessary that the component form-list.component.ts is automatically changed class.

**environment.service.ts**

```
export class EnvironmentService {
  leftSideBarIsOpen = true;
  leftSideBarMainListIsOpen = true;
  leftSideBarFormListIsOpen = false;

  constructor() { }
}
```

**main-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EnvironmentService } from '../../../environment.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-list',
  templateUrl: './main-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-list.component.css']
})
export class MainListComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class') class: String;

  constructor(private environmentService: EnvironmentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.class = this.environmentService.leftSideBarMainListIsOpen 
    ?'display' : 'hide';
  }

  changeSideBarContent(contentComponentView: String) {
    switch (contentComponentView) {
      case 'form-list':
        this.environmentService.leftSideBarMainListIsOpen = false;

        this.environmentService.leftSideBarFormListIsOpen = true;
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

**form-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EnvironmentService } from '../../../environment.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-list',
  templateUrl: './form-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./form-list.component.css']
})
export class FormListComponent implements OnInit {
  @HostBinding('class') class: String;

  constructor(private environmentService: EnvironmentService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.class = this.environmentService.leftSideBarFormListIsOpen ? 
    'display' : 'hide';
  }

  changeSideBarContent(contentComponentView: String) {
    switch (contentComponentView) {
      case 'main-list':
        this.environmentService.leftSideBarFormListIsOpen = false;

        this.environmentService.leftSideBarMainListIsOpen = true;
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can use `ngClass` directive ([documenation](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)) where `display` and `hide` classes will depend on that boolean flags.

```
<some-element [ngClass]="{'hide' : !ctrl.leftSideBarMainListIsOpen, 'display' : ctrl.leftSideBarMainListIsOpen}">
    ...
</some-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can also use ngStyle:

```
<p [ngStyle]="{ display: show ? 'none' : 'block' }">
  Click to hide
</p>
<button (click)="show = !show">Toggle</button>
```